# functions.php not adding css to website?

Tags: php, css

So I went through the forum to find a solution before I post a question, however I have yet to find it. I'm new to wordpress and I'm having a lot of fun learning on how to build my own website. However I am unable to add my css to my website this the code I have below.

**functions.php**

```
<?php 
function fearnothing_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style("style",  get_stylesheet_uri()."css/
        fearnothing.css",false, 'all');


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fearnothing_script_enqueue');
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>lonely spaceship</title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

**footer.php**

```
        <footer>
        <p></p>
    </footer>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

**fearnothing.css**

```
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #91f213;
    background-color:black;
    font: sans-serif;
}

body{
    padding: 20px;
}

h1{
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: do you mean your CSS file is not added?

Comment: Yeah, the css file is not adding to the website. I tried countless different ways to extract the dir of the css file.

Comment: to be clear: you mention functions.php in your question headline, but inside your question you write function.php (hence the missing S). i recently ran into the same issue, so make sure, its called properly, to be loaded at all..

Comment: ahh yes! it is called functions.php . will edit that now in the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you try to add a css file in your theme or plugin. I will provide both examples. Use [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) in combination with [get_theme_file_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) to enqueu a stylesheet in your theme directory.

**For a theme, see example**

```
function add_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/all.css' ), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles' );
```

**For a plugin, see example**

```
function add_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'example-styles-plugin', plugins_url('/assets/css/admin.css', __FILE__), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles' );
```

**For both, add an external URL:**

```
function add_styles() {
    // Add Google Fonts
    wp_enqueue_style('google_fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,500,700', array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to know that you are having fun learning and building your own websites.

Here is the deal:
`get_stylesheet_uri()` function returns the current theme stylesheet. It adds the style.css file from your current theme directory.

The solution:
If you want to enqueue any kind of assets file like CSS or JS on your theme, you have to use get_template_directory_uri() functions instead of get_stylesheet_uri().

Your code should be like this:

```
function fearnothing_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style("style",  get_template_directory_uri()."/assets-file/css/fearnothing.css",false, 'all');


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fearnothing_script_enqueue');
```

`get_template_directory_uri()` function Retrieve theme directory URI.
For more information, you might take a look on codex documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/all.css' ), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles' );
```

This is how i do it.